# next js 14 server component infinit request

Tags: next.js, next.js13

im using nextjs 14. i have a page which is server component that i expored page and generatemetadata from.
its perfectly working on firefox bot on chrom (as i know) the page request get in a loop
only in production
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kisha.png)

```
import { fetchProduct } from "@/request/fetchProduct";

import Product from "./components/Product";

export const generateMetadata = async ({ params }) => {
  const data = await fetchProduct(params.slug);
  return {
    images: [
      {
        url: data?.variants?.[0]?.image ?? "test",
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
      },
    ],
    title: data?.name ?? "test",
    description: data?.short_description ?? "test",
  };
};
const page = async ({ params }) => {
  const data = await fetchProduct(params.slug);
  return <Product data={data} />;
};

export default page;
```

```
export const fetchProduct = async (slug) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(
      DOMAIN + `/api/v1/products/${slug}/`,
      {
        cache: "no-store",
      }
    );
    if (!response.ok) return notFound();

    return await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    notFound();
  }
};
```

when i coment out the generatematadata it gets fixed